# Не могу понять результат декоратора

Tags: декоратор

Написать функцию bang, которая печатает "Boom"
Написать декоратор repeat_n_times, у которого есть параметр n.
Декоратор должен выполнить функцию bang n раз
Не могу понять откуда появляется цифра "4"
Результат программы :
Boom
Boom
Boom
Boom
Boom
Boom
4

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(n):
        result = func()
        for result in range(n):
            func()
        return result
    return wrapper

@decorator
def bang():
    print("Boom")
print(bang(5))
```

Comment: У вас вообще табуляции съехали и данный код не будет выполняться, а выдаст ошибку.

Comment: Когда значение из `range` не нужно обычно пишут `for _ in range(n):`, чтобы подчеркнуть эту не нужность, если бы вы так сделали, то избежали бы одной из ошибок - использования одной переменной для двух разных целей.

Answer (score 3):

Это из-за `print(bang(5))`

`range(5)` это 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
Вы используете `result` в `for`, а значит в конце цикла `result = 4`.

И четверка через `return result` попадает в `print`.

А `Boom` пишет 6 раз вместо 5 из-за лишней `result = func()`